# Razor pages asp-page tag helper not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have a Razor page with the following link to a Delete page for an item:

```
<td><a asp-page="/ProcessLineItem/Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a></td>
```

When the page is loaded, the result of this is simply:

```
<td><a>Delete</a></td>
```

I have a `Delete.cshtml` page located in `Pages\ProcessLineItem`. Furthermore, if I rename `Delete.cshtml` to `Deleter.cshtml` and change the asp-page tag-helper accordingly to `asp-page="/ProcessLineItem/Deleter"`, everything works as expected, and the `<a>` tag is generated correctly. I can only think I have some sort of conflict somewhere and it doesn't know how to generate the route, but all other Delete pages for other objects work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use like this:

```
<td><a href="/ProcessLineItem/Delete?id=@item.Id">Delete</a></td>
```

The error may be caused by your `Pages` folder structure.